# Limited validation for edit form in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using modular MVC with codeigniter. I have a module playlist in which I have a admin controller and I am having a **private $rules variable** for setting the form validation rules.

I have both create and edit functions in the same file and validating both the forms (add,edit which are also created dynamically from only one file form.php).

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->rules);
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters(' <p class="error">', '</p>');
```

These are used in both create and edit functions. some of the fields i dont want to validate in edit mode. Should I need to create different private rules for both of them or is there any better way to handle this in codeigniter since I am new to it. I want to remove validation for **FILE tag** as user dont need to upload at edit mode.

Thanks

Comment: use a flag variable to see the state if it is insert then set all fields mendatory other wise if update then some should be optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer from the CI forums ([original link](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/120221/#819499)).

You can define the rules for create/edit using some form of heirachy, then;

```
<?php
$this->form_validation->set_group_rules('createModule');
$this->form_validation->set_group_rules('editModule');
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
   // whatevere you want
}
?>
```

Or, you could do this;

```
<?php
// This will validate the 'accidentForm' first
$this->form_validation->set_group_rules('createModule');
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
   // whatevere you want
}
// Now we add the 'locationForm' group of rules
$this->form_validation->set_group_rules('editModule');
// And now we validate *both* sets of rules (remember that the createModule rules are still
// there), but it doesn't necessarily matter, since it will simply redo the 'createModule'
// validation while also doing the 'editModule' validation
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
   // whatevere you want
}
?>
```

Below is the code for the extended Form_validation class, saved in the application libraries folder as MY_Form_validation.php

```
<?php
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    /**
     * Set Rules from a Group
     *
     * The default CodeIgniter Form validation class doesn't allow you to
     * explicitely add rules based upon those stored in the config file. This
     * function allows you to do just that.
     *
     * @param string $group
     */
    public function set_group_rules($group = '') {
        // Is there a validation rule for the particular URI being accessed?
        $uri = ($group == '') ? trim($this->CI->uri->ruri_string(), '/') : $group;

        if ($uri != '' AND isset($this->_config_rules[$uri])) {
            $this->set_rules($this->_config_rules[$uri]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

?>
```